# how to avoid reference error in directives

Tags: vuejs2

Is there a way to avoid long checks in v-if(and other directives but mostly it's about v-if) like:

```
... v-if="user && user.data && user.data.password"
```

?

I mean if `user` is `null` then I would get reference error without such checks.

Is it possible to register own modifier all over app?
Something like

```
... v-if.noDataAsFalse="user.data.password"
```

I can use global helper like lodash's _.get() but want to find more declarative way to achieve the same results.

Comment: You'll have to use a library for now. There is a proposal in the works for future versions of javascript. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Comment: just found [fresh proposal](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6982) on implementing custom modifier API that has been closed without any doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the most straightforward way of doing this in Vue at the moment.

In Angular 5 (yes, 5 is here) they have a so called elvis operator (object?.prop?.anotherProp), which allows for safe object traversal.

This idea was brought up on the Vue Github page, but the creator of Vue has some solid arguments against it. You can read more [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4638).

Comment: actually it worked even for Angular 1.0.1: http://jsfiddle.net/y00b860f/

Angular has its own expression parser so no-reference error could raise in JS code only